# rngd is running with /dev/hwrng; boot hangs long at "Initalizing entropy source hwrng"

Tags: boot, embedded, random, yocto

My i.MX6 machine with yocto linux takes horribly long to boot. On the console I can see that it's hanging at initializing the hardware random number generator:

```
Starting system message bus:
[    8.799607] random: dbus-daemon: uninitialized urandom read (12 bytes read)
[    8.818010] random: dbus-daemon: uninitialized urandom read (12 bytes read)
Starting random number generator daemon
Initalizing available sources
Initalizing entropy source hwrng
```

Here the boot hangs for 12 seconds

```
[   20.927096] random: crng init done
Initalizing entropy source jitter
```

`rngd` runs with `-r /dev/hwrng` and seems really quick (around 200kb/s when `dd`ing random).

What else to check where the problem could be?

Comment: Does your board have hardware support for random number generation? If it does then I don't know whats going on - it shouldn't take 12 secs, maybe you are missing the driver for the hardware. If it doesn't have rng hardware then check out [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/)

Comment: The i.MX6 has integrated rng support in the caam module. The `dmesg` displays a lot of caam output, so the module is enabled.